# Displaying shared counter after Threads finished

Tags: java, concurrency

my task is to display shared counter after 2 threads (one incrementing certain number of times one decrementing certain number of times ) have finished. So when first thread finishes it will display the counter, when second one finishes it will display counter again.

I already made a counter class and countingThread class and i think they work fine its just displaying the shared counter im struggling with.

my test class is this so far

```
public static void main() throws InterruptedException{
    Counter counter = new Counter();    
    Thread inc = new CountingThread(counter, +1);
    Thread dec = new CountingThread(counter, -1);

    inc.start();
    dec.start();
}
```

Now After they finish do I use join() or isAlive() ? if so how do i do that ?

Comment: Yup, you answered it yourself... Use the `join()` method, which is an instance method, meaning that you call it on "your thread object" thusly: `inc.join()` ... and the same for `dec`, obviously. You can look these little factiods up in the API doco (which is all online under http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) much faster than asking on a forum, and then use the forums to ask about anything you still don't understand having atleast tried to groc the docs ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use join to have your main thread wait for the inc and dec thread to finish its work.

```
inc.start() // starts inc thread
dec.start() // starts dec thread

inc.join() // Tells main/this thread to wait for inc thread to finish
dec.join() // Tells main/this thread to wait for dec thread to finish
```